# How to add datagridview rows to an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am a beginner in c#, I created one `dataGridView1` in a `Form` to which I added some rows and columns (*without using `DataSet` and `Datatable`*). Now I need to send the data of `dataGridView1` to an xml file. The xml file should **update** whenever I click on that button. I need to do this without using `Datatable` (or tables). I tried the below code (*not working*)

**OnButtonClick**

```
        XmlTextWriter newXml = new XmlTextWriter("d:/newXML.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(dataGridView1.Rows.ToString()); /* May be I am missing something here */
        ds.WriteXml(newXml);
```

xml file is created successfully but showing `<System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection />` in it.

If I add `BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;` before `DataSet`, it is showing error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

**Note:** If the xml file is not their then it should create one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats "Not working ? " are you getting any error, also put a debug point and see if you have any data in your table

Comment: Instead of writing datatable to XML file you can use [DataSet.WriteXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx)

Comment: It seems you've copied part of code from somewhere without understanding what it is doing.

Comment: @Mr_Green But then how do you know these lines will serve your purpose?

Comment: I removed my comments because I edited my question very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Save DataGridView to Xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053387/c-sharp-save-datagridview-to-xml-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate a `DataTable` and populate it from your `dataGridView1` control:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Customers");
        // copy the correct structure from datagridview to the table
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(column.Name, typeof(string));
        }

        // populate the datatable from datagridview
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add();
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
            {
                table.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex] = dataGridView1[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value;
            }
        }
```

then continue with the rest of your code:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(table);
    ds.WriteXml("d:/newXML.xml", System.Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

Comment: It is showing Error: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the **C#** world !

A good start to solve your problem should be to use **Serialization**, it's really handy when you need to save Objects into an XML file.

I don't know how you store the Objects that fills the **DataGrid** but if you can, you should make them serializable, add some methods like Load(), Save(), etc.

Read this for more informations : [MSDN - Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swxzdhc0.aspx)

You'll find plenty informations on how to do this, a little bit harsh to implement when you start but saves you a damn lot of time further on the road !

Hope it will help.

**EDIT 1 :**

Just saw your edits, it seems like you're not using Objects, just plain inserts. In that case, my solution won't help but think about it for more complex situations...